# How to connect laptop to digital camera - bypass memory card & have photo show on screen

Tags: windows, webcam, camera

I am trying to create a simple photo booth for a dance.

What I would like to do is use a Windows laptop, USB cable and digital camera on a tripod. I would like for the camera to bypass its memory card (due to the volume of photos) and save right to the computer's hard drive. It would be great if the photo could immediately appear onscreen.

Is this possible? I have access to many different cameras.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a USB web cam ($20 for basic, $40 can buy you 720p quality) and any of the freeware/shareware/paid applications out there to build your photo booth. his way, the computer drives the process of taking the pictures, rather than the camera.

Here are a couple of links to applications offering this functionality: [Link1](http://photoboof.com/), [Link2](http://sparkbooth.com/).
Feel free to Google for better results.

Enjoy!

Answer (score 0):

I have the FujiFilm FinePix F401 it has the capability of serving as a webcam.
All I need to do is connect the camera to the computer in "USB CAMERA" mode and after installing the drivers, i'm capable of using it exactly as you want.

So, coming directly to what you said, you'll have to make a list of all the cameras that you have available and then find if any of them offer the feature that I described.
(It is also available in the camera menu, under setup)

Comment: Check you video cameras as well, a lot of them have this facility.